# HTML Build system in Sublime Text 2

Tags: sublimetext2, build-system

I'm struggling to successfully build a HTML build system in Sublime Text 2. I am running Windows 7. 
This is the code for my build system:

```
{
    "cmd": ["open", "-a", "Google Chrome", "$file"]
}
```

This is the error I recieve when I try and build a html file:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: ['open', '-a', 'Google Chrome', 'C:\\Users\\Soham\\Desktop\\hello.html']]
[dir: C:\Users\Soham\Desktop]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem]
[Finished]
```

I have no idea why this error is ocurring and have searched the web for an explanation.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `open` command is only available on OSX systems. You have two options - you can use Sublime's built-in "Open in Browser" functionality by right-clicking in any open HTML file and selecting `Open in Browser`, or you can modify your build system to just point to the correct location of `chrome.exe`:

```
"cmd": [ "C:\\Users\\YourUserName\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", "$file"]
```

replacing `YourUserName` with the correct value, and ensuring that this actually **is** the location of `chrome.exe` on your system.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Chrome with Windows 7, you could run successfully the following:

```
{
   "cmd": ["C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe", "$file"]
}
```